# How to convert any time zone into UTC using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I want to convert the user's time, eg. `08:45 P.M`, to UTC time zone. How can I do that?

```
if ($request->open_at)
{
  $time = Carbon::parse($request->open_at)->toUTCString();
  dd($time);
  $query->whereTime('open_at', '>=', $time);
}
```

Comment: If the string you have is just `08:45 P.M` then this can't be done reliably, unless you can guarantee that all your users are in the same timezone. You need to know what the user's original timezone is in order to calculate the hours to subtract/add in order to convert to UTC

Comment: User's time zone is `parse()` second argument. But, do you have such information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this PHP approach:

```
$time = new DateTime("08:45 P.M");
$time ->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
echo $time ->format("Y-m-d H:i:s e");
```

Answer (score 2):

Like such, but unless you're always starting from the system timezone (configured in PHP), date must already have the correct timezone set for this to work, like others have mentioned.

```
$time = Carbon::parse($request->open_at);
$time->setTimezone('UTC');
...
```

Carbon extends the DateTime object including [setTimezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php)

Answer (score 2):

User's time zone can be fed into the optional second argument of `parse()`. I've also been unable to find any `toUTCString()` method (). All together:

```
$userTimeZone = 'Europe/Berlin'; // We'll come to this later
$time = Carbon::parse($request->open_at, $userTimeZone)->setTimezone('UTC');
echo $time->format('r');
```

For example:

```
foreach (['Asia/Tokyo',  'Europe/Berlin', 'America/Los_Angeles'] as $userTimeZone) {
    echo "$userTimeZone\n";
    $time = Carbon::parse('08:45 P.M', $userTimeZone);
    echo $time->format('r'), "\n";
    $time->setTimezone('UTC');
    echo $time->format('r'), "\n\n";
}
```

```
Asia/Tokyo
Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:45:00 +0900
Fri, 24 Dec 2021 11:45:00 +0000

Europe/Berlin
Fri, 24 Dec 2021 20:45:00 +0100
Fri, 24 Dec 2021 19:45:00 +0000

America/Los_Angeles
Thu, 23 Dec 2021 20:45:00 -0800
Fri, 24 Dec 2021 04:45:00 +0000
```

Of course, all of this is pointless if you don't know the user's time zone.
Do you have such information? The easiest way is to probably just ask, although you can also use some tricks to try and guess, such as:

- Client-side JavaScript
- Geolocation APIs

Answer (score -1):

Carbon has `->utc()` method (equivalent to `setTimezone('UTC')`) and Laravel query build can take Carbon object without having to format it as a string:

```
$query->whereTime('open_at', '>=', Carbon::parse($request->open_at)->utc());
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the set timezone function to convert time

```
$time = Carbon::parse($request->open_at);
$time->setTimezone('UTC');
```